# TinyMCE v3 plugin using jQuery for dialog behaviour

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm trying to create a simple TinyMCE plugin with these features:

- when clicking a `div.my-todo-list-container` a dialog will appear
- the div will be selected as jQuery object
- Add, Delete buttons for each list item
- on Delete the item will be deleted
- on Add a new item with same behaviour (Add, Delete options) will appear
- on Save the list of items will update the `div.my-todo-list-container` contents.

(It's just an example. In my case the items are more complex.)

I'm OK with jQuery part. I already have an implementation for my behaviour. Also I solved the basic structure for my plugin. The custom button appears in menu, on click the dialog appears, also when selecting the custom div in editor, the button is selected.

But I'm not sure how to integrate my jQuery code here. Now I have, in my `dialog.html` template:

```
<form onsubmit="tinymce.activeEditor.plugins.my_plugin._onSave();" action="#">
...
```

and

```
<script>
  tinymce.activeEditor.plugins.my_plugin._onEdit();
</script>
```

used to call my methods defined in this way

```
_onSave: function() {
  alert("Saved");
},

_onEdit: function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $content = $("#" + tinyMCE.activeEditor.editorId);
  });
},
```

The `$content` seems really strange:

```
$content.length
1
typeof $content
"object"
$content instanceof jQuery
true
$content.html()
returns the html code as expected
```

BUT:

```
$content.find('div').length
0 - when I have a lot of divs...
```

I expect to get a jquery dom element, to generate my dialog contents and behaviour and the just save the new content. But it seems like I'm on wrong way. Can't have it working. Any hint or solution for this type of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusing part was related to the fact my editor is loaded in an iframe. Using contextual search the main problem was solved. Example: `$content = $("iframe").contents().find('div.my-todo-list-container').first();`

Also I found simple solutions for update or add new content:

```
$old_section.replaceWith(html_content); // update

tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(html_content); // in case section is missing I use this to create a section in given selection
```

I just replace my old section with new one, on save.